# Rank of a matrix from a $5\times7$ matrix with a basis of $3$ vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The question in my book is as follows:

> If the subspace of all solutions of $Ax=0$ has a basis consisting of thee vectors and if $A$ is a $5\times7$ matrix, what is the rank of $A$?

Now i thought because the basis consist of three vectors that the rank was also $3$. Because the rank is the dimension of the column space of $A$ and because the basis of $A$ is the column space i thought the answer is $3$. But in my book the answer was that the dimension of the null space was $3$ and because of that $7 - 3$ is $4$ and the rank is $4\ldots$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the rank-nullity theorem: $A$ is the matrix of a linear map $u$ from $K^7$ to $K^5$ ($K$ is the base field), so $$\operatorname{rk} u +\dim\ker u=7,\quad\text{hence}\quad \operatorname{rk} u = \operatorname{rk} A=4. $$

Comment: Ok, but they say that the rank of an matrix A also equals to the number of piviot positions in A and satisfies the equation rank a + dim Nul a = n. and the basis consist of 3 vectors so A had 3 piviots?

Comment: It's bases of the subspace `Null A ` that has  $3$ vectors. $A$ has $7-3=4$ pivots.

Comment: Ok that now I understand, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $A$ is a representation in the standard basis of the linear transformation

$$f:\Bbb R^7\to \Bbb R^5,\; x\mapsto Ax$$
and by the hypothesis $\dim\ker A=3$ so by the rank-nullity theorem

$$\operatorname{rank}(A)=\dim\Bbb R^7-\dim\ker A=4$$